# how do you slugify a url?

Tags: python, flask, slug

I'm using slugify, and I have no idea how to make my post title slugified, do I need to make a new column in my post? I've been stuck on this all day long.

Any suggestions ?

**Views.py**

```
@app.route('/posts/<title>')
@login_required
def show(title):

    link = db.session.query(Post).filter_by(title = title).one()
    link2 = slugify(link.title)

    return render_template("post.html", post=link2,  pid=id, title=link2)
```

**Models.py**

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80))
    body = db.Column(db.Text)




    def __init__(self, title, body):
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
```

**error message**

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2760, in one
    raise orm_exc.NoResultFound("No row was found for one()")
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound: No row was found for one()
```

Comment: Try loggin `title`. Is it received properly?

Comment: The error only says that it cannot find any row, while you expect one row. I usually use something like `Post.query.filter_by(title=title).first()`, then check if the result is null or not.

Comment: @btquanto can you rephrase that i dont understand ?

Comment: Post.query.filter_by(title=title).first() works, but it doesnt when i put slugify on it

Comment: I assume that you're using `url_for('show', title=title)`. This doesn't work because you aren't passing the title, you're passing the slug. When you query the database, no titles match the slug. If you need to query by the slug, then yes, you should store it in your database.

Comment: how would you do that dirn, i tried making a slug column with the same attributes that the title has, but still no success. How would you go about integrating this

Comment: Lat's say the value of the slug is `"some_post_slug"`. Your query is looking for a `Post` that has the exact title `"some_post_slug"`, but it cannot find it. You are using `one()` method, which always expect to have exact one result returning from the query, but the query cannot find anything, so there are 0 results -> crash.

Comment: I think what @dirn says is that a title is not a slug. You may have a post titled "Some post title", the the slug should be something like "some_post_title". If you want to query the `Post` by the slug, then you should have an attribute `Post.slug` which stores the slug `"some_post_title"` for querying. Then you may query `Post.query.filter_by(slug=slug).first()`

Comment: @btquanto my brain is starting to connect the dots, do i need to specify a slug column in the post model then and how would i successful implement this  ?

Comment: How do you store the slug? Did you add `self.slug = slugify(title)` to `Post.__init__`?

Comment: @dirn no, i havent tried that yet, i will give it a go right now, when you mean post. init do you mean the post model ? kinda confused

Comment: Yes. That's the only thing you showed named `Post`.

Comment: @dim i did not add it to the self init, should i go do that ?

self.slug = slug ?

Answer (score 2):

You take `slug` instead of `title` in your view and query database based on slug. While creating post you `slugify` the title and store it in `slug`  field.

**Views.py**

```
@app.route('/posts/<slug>')
@login_required
def show(slug):
    post = db.session.query(Post).filter_by(slug = slug).first()
    if post:
        return render_template("post.html", post=post)

    abort(404)
```

Note that we are using `.first` instead of `.one` here because `.first` return `None` if no posts found whereas `.one` raises an exception which you need to catch and make flow according to it.

If there is no post found then we are returning `404`.

**Models.py**

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80))
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True)

    def __init__(self, title, body):
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
        self.slug = slugify(title)
```

Comment: Thanks so much vivek, I want to point out that i used

  slug = db.Column(db.String(80)) 

but i did not add the index = true attribute, when i tried before, thanks for that

the way you explained it makes alot of sense.

however, i keep getting this error 

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: posts.slug [SQL: 'SELECT posts.id AS posts_id, posts.title AS posts_title, posts.body AS posts_body, posts.slug AS posts_slug \nFROM posts']

Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: @EliHood I think you haven't created the column `slug` yet in your posts database table. You can manually insert the column in database or if you are using `flask-sqlalchemy` then you can do `db.create_all()` to create table.

Comment: it works now, what i did is used a different sql db name, 

instead of test.db, i used test12.db this is where you indentify your db name on the __init__file

like this

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join( tempfile.gettempdir(), 'test122.db')


but still would like to know how to clear your db completely

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are using a title for the posts such as "This is my first blog post" which is great. I am also guessing that you want to use the slug in order to have a more URL friendly permalink for each post. In the previous case the slug would be something like "this-is-my-first-blog-post"

So given a slug, your post would be available at the /posts/{unique-post-slug} route and not /posts/{title}. My suggestion would be to store the slug in the database in order to retrieve the post since reverse slugify isn't so easy.

To sum up your model should be:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80))
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    slug = db.Column(db.Text, index=True)

    def __init__(self, title, body):
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
        self.slug = slugfiy(title)
```

Notice the `index=True` option. This is done for faster querying.

And the route that should render your post would be

```
@app.route('/posts/<slug>')
@login_required
def show(slug):

    post = db.session.query(Post).filter_by(slug=slug).one()

    return render_template("post.html", post=post)
```

In your post.html file you can use all the post fields (id, title, body, slug) as post.id, post.title, etc

Comment: `db.Text` is for storing multiline texts instead you can use `db.string`.